# How to wrap dynamic HTML from database around Vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to be able to wrap custom HTML around my Vue template content.  As you can see below, it's not simply inserting html content using `<div v-html="HtmlWrapperTopHalf">` because that will automatically close any unclosed tags.  The tags will always be closed in the bottom half of the dynamic HTML.  Basically, I'm looking to insert the Vue template code into my dynamic template HTML.

I also can't just assume what's in the dynamic HTML and build that inside the Vue template.  This HTML comes from a RichText editor that my customers create on their own.  They just insert a placeholder `{{MAIN_CONTENT}}` in the middle of their dynamic template and that's where the Vue Template functionality should appear.

**Page.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        //Top half of dynamic XHTML wrapper goes here

        <p>Inner Content Here</p>
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB />
        <!-- etc. --->
        <p>More Inner Content</p>

        //Bottom half of dynamic XHTML wrapper goes here
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    axios.get("getHtmlContent").then((result) =>{
       console.log("top", result.data.HtmlWrapperTopHalf)
       console.log("bottom", result.data.HtmlWrapperBottomHalf)
    });
</script>
```

**console.log**

```
top: <div class="my-dynamic-class" id="my-unique-id"><h1>DYNAMIC TITLE</h1>
bottom: <div id="my-dynamic-footer">custom footer text</div></div>
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<div>
    <div class="my-dynamic-class" id="my-unique-id"><h1>DYNAMIC TITLE</h1>

    <p>Inner Content Here<p>
    <div>Hello from ComponentA!!</div>
    <div>Hello from ComponentB!!</div>
    <!-- etc. --->
    <p>More Inner Content<p>

    <div id="my-dynamic-footer">custom footer text</div></div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this diagram of the concept will help:
[image]

Comment: What is purpose to separate starting and ending tag?

Comment: @Daniel the dynamic html initially isn't separated, it is full XHTML with a placeholder in the middle `{{MAIN_CONTENT}}` and I split it on that delimiter so I can wrap it around the inner page content.  Previously in WebForms.aspx (which we are migrating away from) this was easy because using an <asp:Literal> didn't automatically close the open tags from the top half.  v-html closes them, though, which breaks the "wrapping" effect.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand that ;) Why in top/bottom parts are unclosed tags?

Comment: @Daedalus sorry - just a typo.  I fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that other components can be a part of this split up html content, using the `render` syntax to generate a slot within the content seems to be the only alternative.

```
   render(createElement) {
      return createElement(
         'div', { 'class': 'hello'},
         this.$slots.default
      )
   },
```

Have your axios component be built out within the render ([see docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)), and then use this as a `slot` to fill in within future components.

E.g. `<ClientHtmlInject> <Comp1/><Comp2/> </ClientHtmlInjection>`

Comment: I'm worried this method will close off the top HTML's tags also but I'll give this a shot!

Comment: @RichC I updated the answer to have the injection I think you are looking for. Does that work?

Comment: I mention why I can't use v-html in my post. I don't think this will work for the same reason.  :(

Comment: Does the bottom half not close all of the tags within the top half @RichC? If so, this injections of `'<p>My injected content</p>' /* i.e. this.customHTML*/` should do it

Comment: this would work if `this.customHtml` was possible.  I added more detail to the question.

Comment: @RichC I think I have an answer for you. Typing it out now.

Comment: ok - I'll check this out and see if it works

Comment: Starting to think the only option I have is to convert my HTML wrapper to json data and then parse through it and create HTML controls in a component and then use a slot for the inner content.

Comment: yeah- "this is the way"

Comment: @t-woody Ran into a huge roadblock.  I can't get the string of XHTML into a format that easily converted into something that I can create elements with javascript.

Comment: @RichC Do you have an example? This might be a separate question?

Comment: @t-woody yeah since this is a different question, I created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050421/how-to-take-an-xhtml-string-and-render-it-on-a-webpage-using-javascript